# Chef - knife vault refresh no method error

Tags: chef-infra, knife

```
DEBUG: Chef::HTTP calling Chef::HTTP::JSONInput#handle_response
/Users/nick/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/chef-vault-3.3.0/lib/chef/knife/vault_refresh.rb:44:in `run': undefined method `skip_reencryption=' for #<ChefVault::Item:0x007fa62bd010a0> (NoMethodError)
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/lib/chef/knife.rb:442:in `block in run_with_pretty_exceptions'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/lib/chef/knife.rb:441:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/lib/chef/knife.rb:219:in `run'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:156:in `run'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/chef-13.2.20/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/knife:263:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/knife:263:in `<main>'
```

I receive this error when I run `knife vault refresh {folder} {item}`.

This is the result of the prompt from `knife bootstrap`:

```
192.168.0.17 [2017-11-01T14:11:54-07:00] ERROR: {vault-item} is encrypted for you, but your private key failed to decrypt the contents.  (if you regenerated your client key, have an administrator of the vault run 'knife vault refresh')
```

Comment: Is there a reason you installed chef-vault yourself rather than using the version in ChefDK? Unlikely to be related, but good to check.

Comment: @coderanger I don't recall installing chef vault my self.

Comment: It's in your local gems, so you did :)

Comment: @coderanger Thanks for the info. I forgot to ask how you knew. I used a `depends` and `includes`. Not sure why I did it other than being a noob and probably seeing it done here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, installing a gem would be something like `chef gem install` generally.